# Why do I need an explicit type argument list here?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, covariance

I am writing a generic FSM library:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

trait State {
  def isAcceptState: Boolean
}

trait FSM[T <: FSM[T, A, S], -A, +S <: State] { this: T =>
  def state: S

  def resume(input: A): T
}

object FSM {
  @tailrec
  def resumeUntilAccept[T <: FSM[T, A, S], A, S <: State](fsm: T, inputs: Iterator[A]): T = {
    if (inputs.hasNext) {
      val input = inputs.next
      val newFSM = fsm.resume(input)
      if (newFSM.state.isAcceptState) {
        newFSM
      } else {
        resumeUntilAccept[T, A, S](newFSM, inputs) // THIS LINE OF CODE
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception("not enough inputs")
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the type argument list on the line marked `// THIS LINE OF CODE`, I get the following error:

> Main.scala:22: error: inferred type arguments `[T,A,Nothing]` do not conform to method `resumeUntilAccept`'s type parameter bounds `[T <: FSM[T,A,S],A,S <: State]`
>
> ```
>    resumeUntilAccept(newFSM, inputs)
>    ^
> ```

Why is `Nothing` inferred instead of `S`? And even then, why does it not conform? `Nothing` is clearly a subtype of `State`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is limitation of Scala type inference for type constructors, see [SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712).

You can help compiler by changing type of argument to `fsm: FSM[T, A, S]`. The following simplified snippet slightly differs from original, but at least it compiles.

```
trait State

trait FSM[T <: FSM[T, A, S], -A, +S <: State]

object FSM {
  def resumeUntilAccept[T <: FSM[T, A, S], A, S <: State](fsm: FSM[T, A, S], inputs: Iterator[A]): T = {
    val newFSM: T = ???
    resumeUntilAccept(newFSM, inputs)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because type S is not inferred from arguments until FSM is known. So compiler can't compare these S's. "Nothing" not conform to "unknown S" because of same reason.

```
trait Z[X]
scala> def aaa[A <: Z[B] ,B](a: A):A = aaa(a)
inferred type arguments [A,Nothing] do not conform

scala> def aaa[A <: Z[B], B](a: A):A = aaa[A, B](a) 
aaa: [A <: Z[B], B](a: A)A
```

or even

```
scala> def aaa[A <: Z[B], B](a: Z[B]):A = aaa(a) 
aaa: [A <: Z[B], B](a: Z[B])A
```